# Promise in promise.all doesn't returns value

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I would like below the "**queryPexels**" function to return the value for the imgSuggestions variable, which does not happen
**(EDITTED)** I pasted the rest of the code, I believe the problem is somewhere in the syntax of the promise all

```js
  let foundProduct; //product id
  let imgSuggestions; //pexels
  let labelSeggestions; // OpenAI
  let headingSuggestions; // OpenAI Title
  let fontDownloadLink; // Font link

  if (
    foundRegistries.products.some((product) => product.id === productId)
  ) {

    foundProduct = foundRegistries.products.filter(
      (product) => product.id === productId
    );
  
    let queryImage = foundProduct[0].productName.toString()
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        await Promise.all([
          (imgSuggestions = await queryPexels(
            pexelsConfig,
            queryImage,
            photosPerPage,
          )),
          (labelSeggestions = await queryOpenAiLabel(
            openAiConfig,
            foundProduct[0].productName,
            foundProduct[0].targetAudience
          )),
          (headingSuggestions = await queryOpenAiHeading(
            openAiConfig,
            foundProduct[0].productName
          )), 
          (fontDownloadLink = await getFonts(
            googleConfig,
            foundRegistries.font,
            foundRegistries.fontVariant
          )),
        ]).then(() =>
          resolve(
            {
              productId : productId,
              imgSuggestions : imgSuggestions,
              labelSeggestions : labelSeggestions,
              headingSuggestions : headingSuggestions,
              fontDownloadLink : fontDownloadLink,
            }
          )
        );
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    });
  } else {
    return {
      Error: "No product found. Please check provided product ID.",
    };
  }
```

It's her my function async **queryPexels**:

```js
async function queryPexels(pexelsConfig, query, photosPerPage) {
  // const client = createClient(pexelsConfig.key);
  queryOpenAiKeywords(
    invocation.openAiConfig,
    query
  ).then(res => {
    const query = res
    translateTxt(query).then(translate =>{
      const trad = translate.toString()
      const client = new Client({ apiKey: pexelsConfig.key});
      getPexelsPhotos(trad,client,photosPerPage).then(response =>{
        const photos = choosePhotos(response.photos)
        console.log(photos) // THIS PHOTOS IS PRINTED BUT IMGSUGGESTIONS IS EQUAL TO UNDEFINED
        return photos // BECAUSE THIS RETURNS ISN'T GET OF BY PROMISE ALL
      }).catch( err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }).catch( err => {
      console.log(err)
    });
  })

}
```

When I print the imgSuggestions after Promise.all i've got undefined value, but the queryPexels console.log(photos) is succeeding.

Comment: You are creating several new promises without returning them. `return` in inner function doesn't return from outer one

Comment: Your `queryPixels` function doesn't have a return statement, and it is marked as `async` so it is implicitly returning a promise that resolves to `undefined`. Try returning your promise in that function instead: `return queryOpenAiKeywords(...).then(...)`.

Comment: @CRice, op also doesn't return the `translateTxt` and `getPexelsPhotos`

Comment: Also, why do you create these variables like `imgSuggestions ` without declaring them first?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski All the variables were declared and only imgSuggestions is gettin undefined

Comment: Why do you use `Promise.all` if you declare these variables?

Comment: Cause it'll be resolved in a body like {imgSuggestion:imgSuggestions, labelSuggestions:labelSuggestion, etc...}

Comment: I don't know how does the code looks like later, but assuming that you are using these variables in `then` it seems like it's unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added missing returns, should fix the issue

```
async function queryPexels(pexelsConfig, query, photosPerPage) {
  // here
  return queryOpenAiKeywords(
    invocation.openAiConfig,
    query
  ).then(res => {
    const query = res
    // here
    return translateTxt(query).then(translate =>{
      const trad = translate.toString()
      const client = new Client({ apiKey: pexelsConfig.key});
      // here
      return getPexelsPhotos(trad,client,photosPerPage).then(response =>{
        const photos = choosePhotos(response.photos)
        console.log(photos)
        return photos
      }).catch( err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }).catch( err => {
      console.log(err)
    });
  })

}
```